# Setting value of AccountId / ContactId on AccountContactRelation by trigger using external ID

Tags: account, externalid

I have created a custom field on my **AccountContactRelation** called **SurrogateId__c** and I set configured it to be an *External Identifier*.

When I create an **AccountContactRelation** from an external service, a trigger performs text-extraction from the surrogate id (something like "companyIdentifier_contactIdentifier"), looks up both account and contact and set them.

This works great the first time a record with a given **SurrogateId** companyIdentifier_contactIdentifier is upserted, but on the second upsert 
my code fails:

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This contact already has a relationship with
>   this company.: [ContactId]

Are external ID correclty supported by AccountContactRelation? Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Which field have you marked as external id? If its on AccountContactRelation and also marked as unique, it will not allow multiple records having same contact and account ids.

Comment: the surrogate key is marked as external id

Comment: I don't see any such field here in [AccountContactRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrelation.htm), to get better support you should add more detail and code as well.

Comment: I mention SurrogateId twice?

Comment: Ah I see you edited the post and added the information. That is the standard error, which means you cannot create additional relationship between same Contact and Account. In your trigger, you would need to avoid creating relationship if it already exists.

Comment: It is an upsert so I am not creating an additional relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55214/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-edmondo1984).

Answer (score 1):

Upsert feature does not support for few junction objects in salesforce,  AccountContactRelation object is one of them.